# Can not import videos from cloud storage

Tags: video-intelligence-api

I am trying to make custom model AutoML Video Classification UI. I can not import data from cloud storage bucket. I have mention below the error which is occurred. Already I have changed the csv file into two columns then another error was occurred : *Cannot find the referenced file: in request.* like this.

can you give me the sample csv or correct way to fix this issues. thank you!

I have attached ss of csv file.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ng19P.png)

*Has critical error in root level csv gs://vocalis/Nicetomeetyou/all_data.csv line 1: Expected 2 columns only, but found 4 columns.*